# How to use my own custom directive on my component in angular 4 and above

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-components

I want use like this:

```
<v-button uppercase>test</v-button>
```

my component and directive as follows:

```
@Component({
    selector: "v-button",
    template: "<button class="if component has uppercase directive set 'uppercase css class' here"></button>"
})
export class ButtonComponent{
}

@Directive({
   selector : "[uppercase]"
})
export class UppercaseDirective{
}
```

and i expect this:

```
<button class="uppercase">test</button>
```

thanks for helps.

Solution : for thank you @Wand Maker for giving me the tip

```
@Component({
selector: "v-button",
template: "<button #uppercaseFlag class="if component has uppercase directive set 'uppercase css class' here"></button>"
})
export class ButtonComponent{
 @ViewChild('uppercaseFlag') uppercaseElement: ElementRef;
}

@Directive({
 selector : "[uppercase]",
 providers : [ButtonComponent]
})
export class UppercaseDirective{
 ngAfterContentInit(): void {
 this.renderer.addClass(this.button.uppercaseElement.nativeElement, "uppercase");
 }
 constructor(private readonly renderer: Renderer2, private readonly button: ButtonComponent) { }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directive needs to access the `button` child and add class attribute to it.
To do that, you can inject `ElementRef` in directive constructor to obtain reference to host element `v-button`, and then, wait for the component to get initialized - after which in `ngAfterContentInit` method - you can assign `uppercase` style to first child of `v-button` - which will be a `button` element.  If you do change template of `v-button`, you may have to adjust this part of the code.

Here is the directive code:

```
@Directive({
   selector : "[uppercase]"
})
export class UppercaseDirective implements  AfterContentInit {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
  }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.el.nativeElement.children[0].className='uppercase';
  }
}
```

In addition, you may also want to update your `v-button` template to have `ng-content` so that buttons can be assigned a text/name like this:

```
 <v-button uppercase>Test</v-button>
```

Here is updated component code:

```
@Component({
    selector: "v-button",
    template: "<button><ng-content></ng-content></button>"
})
export class ButtonComponent{
}
```